# How to find and skip special characters at the start and end of the word

Tags: java, regex

New to regex and using following code to find if a word contains special characters at the end/start.

```
String s = "K-factor:";
        String regExp = "^[^<>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*\\]\\\\()\\[0-9_+]*$";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regExp).matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Start: "+ matcher.start());
            System.out.println("End: "+ matcher.end());
            System.out.println("Group: "+ matcher.group());
            s = s.substring(0, matcher.start());
        }
```

Would like to find if there's any special character(: in this sample code) at the start or end of the string. Trying to skip the character.
Neither compile time error nor output.

Comment: You want to match if there are characters other than letters at the start and end? Then use `"^\\P{L}|\\P{L}$"`. Your regex does not match `K-factor` as it contains `:` at the end.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew Working great. Please do post as answer so others can refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your regex matches a whole string that does not contain the chars you defined in the character class. The string in question does not match that pattern since it contains `:`.

You might consider splitting the pattern into two parts to check for the unwanted chars at the start or end using an alternation group:

```
String regExp = "^[<>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*\\]\\\\()\\[0-9_+]|[<>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*\\]\\\\()\\[0-9_+]$";
```

Here, the pattern has a `^<special_char_class>|<special_char_class>$` structure, `^` anchors the match at start, `$` anchors the match at the string end, and `|` is the alternation operator. Note I removed the `^` from the start of the character class to make them *positive* rather than *negated*, so that they could match those chars/ranges defined in the class.

Alternatively, since you seem to just match a string if it contains a non-letter at the start/end, you may  use a

```
String regExp = "^\\P{L}|\\P{L}$";
```

that is Unicode letter aware or - ASCII only:

```
String regExp = "^\\P{Alpha}|\\P{Alpha}$";
```